# Server 2003 Share a Folder on a remote system

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share

Is it possible on Server 2003 to share a folder that resides on another computer?

\\Server1 d:\MyShare < Not Shared

\\Server2 \\Server1\D$\MyShare  < MyShare

from network it should look like Server1 has no shares but Server2 has the share

reasone being...several programs are hardcoded to look to server2 for the fileshare but we need the files to reside on a different box for the time being

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DFS Namespaces can be server-local or domain-based. The File Server Migration Toolkit from Microsoft uses server-local DFS Namespaces to migrate file servers while keeping the netbios name the same. So DFS will do what you want, as long as server2 is Server 2000 or later.

What it won't do is hide the share on server1 but you can use a hidden share, \server1\myshare$ for that.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [Distributed Filesystem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782417(WS.10).aspx) (DFS). It can help you do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: unfortunently it has to look like it is on Server2 not a different domain based path

Comment: @Christohper: You can use DFS to do exactly what you're describing to make a folder on "Server1" appear to be shared by "Server2". You don't have to use the "Domain DFS" and a different namespace. DFS will definitely do what you want.

Comment: @Christopher: Have a look at the section titled "Characteristics of Namespace Types" in the link in my posting. A "Stand-Alone" DFS root installed on "Server2" will allow shares on "Server2" to "point to" folders on "Server1", and the share names will all appear in \\Server2\sharename format (i.e. not using the domain's name).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to share a drive from one server out from another.

What you can do is look at DFS.  This will allow you to have a sharing "namespace" so that you have shares that looking something like \yourdomain\shares\share1 and \yourdomain\shares\share2 where share1 can be from Server 1 and share2 be from Server 2 and your users will not know this and only see the \yourdomain\shares namespace.

Comment: unfortunently it has to look like it is on Server2 not a different domain based path

Comment: As others mentioned, in this case, use a server-local DFS namespace rather than domain-based.